# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code - using CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa, cocoapods

I'm getting the following error when building my project: `Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`.
[image]

This is what I have in my `[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks`:
[image]

I've also done a `pod deintegrate` and `pod install` but these frameworks continue to show in red:

[image]

I'm on `Xcode Version 12.4` and my mac has an `Apple M1` chip. Any thoughts as to what I could do to resolve this error?

Comment: My issue has been resolved by following below link https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/11828

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Clearing the Excluded Architectures solved the issue. I originally had `arm64` and `x86_64` excluded.

[image]

Comment: After clearing I got this error: Target Integrity (Xcode): The linked framework 'Pods_Runner.framework' is missing one or more architectures required by this target: arm64.

Comment: @MKarimi Add  arm64 x86_64 in. Architectures>Excluded Architectures>Debug> Any iOS Simulator SDK : arm64 x86_64

Answer (score 2):

Did you solve your issue?
I got the one of solutions.

1. First of all, you have to delete the files which are red of iOS, Frameworks . They don't exist anymore, so you shouldn't include them to archive.
2. then clean up your builds.
   (click Xcode -> product -> clean build folder)
3. go to archive.
   (click Xcode -> product -> archive)

If you don't use M1, then you have to exclude architectures "arm64".

That's it.
Hope it works.

Comment: Simply running `Clean Build Folders` seems to have solved it for me. Mind was specificly to do with `FirebaseAnalytics`. Thanx. BTW, I'm not sure what you meant by #3. Can you clarify your answer?

Comment: I mean, just click 'archive' button  in your Xcode as I mentioned #2.

Answer (score 1):

1. clear all files inside Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
2. List item clean & build again from xcode

Answer (score 0):

if you're using nvm make sure you don't have another globally installed version of Node/npm.

If you aren't sure whether or not you have a global version, go to your bash_profile/zshrc and comment the three nvm initialization lines (export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" [...]), then open a new terminal and do node --version, if it still finds something it means that you have a global version somewhere, and you can find its path with which node.

In my case I'm using Homebrew, and I had a global version of Node that I wasn't even aware coming from the yarn formula, I discovered it after running brew uses --installed node. I went ahead and uninstalled yarn using `brew uninstall --force yarn`, which automatically uninstalled its node/npm dependency, then uncommented the nvm initialization lines, and then I reinstalled yarn using nvm's npm with npm i -g yarn, and now everything works.

Another way, after installing node via  `brew install node` RUN `sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node`

restart xcode and try to build again.