iOS Build fail only when run through Jenkins
We have been using our build setup for few years now. However we are getting an error in out iOS build only when it run through Jenkins for few days now.
Out setup is as below.

CICD - Jenkin Jobs
Jenkins node- running on an iMac x86_64(Mac OS Ventura 13.6, Xcode- 15.1, iPhone SDK 17.2)
Agent connection - SSH
Build script - Using Fastlane (latest version 2.2.0)

There was no recent changes done to the Jenkins node or the connection mechanism recently.
When we execute the Jenkins job it errors out during Archiving stage indicating following error

ARCHIVE FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/myjenkinsuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PoPoc-ghliacqvmeaczodimbswpjdefbrk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PoPoc/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/PoPoc.build/Release-iphoneos/PoPoc.build/Script-9B3D469C72BEFC2B2114A431.sh (in target 'PoPoc' from project 'PoPoc')
(1 failure)
[23:16:36]: [31mExit status: 65[0m

The interesting thing is when we run the same build commands from the Jenkins node via a terminal the build succeeds. Also when build through Xcode (within the Jenkins node) it completes without any errors.
Following was attempted:

Clearing the workspace before running the Jenkins job
Clearing out the Derived data folder
Pod deintegrate and POD install

At the moment we execute the fastlane script from within the Jenkins Node to create builds but this is not ideal as the access to the node has been granted only to a limited number of people.
Glad if anyone can point us in the direction to investigate this as we are running out of ideas.

Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/69771091/833395

While it has valuable info, it didn;t helped us. In our case the build was successful via XCode and when directly done in the server.

I think your server is not installing pods itself. You have already installed pods on your local machine. Then try to update cocoapods, https://stackoverflow.com/q/76058465/833395, if it works

We did two things to get it resolved. Both might not be needed.

Updated the fastlane to the latest 2.220.0 (I don;t think this fixed it)
We specifically open the keychain for the SSH connection by adding following lines to the ~/.ssh/rc file


#!/bin/bash
security  unlock-keychain -p YOUR_LOGIN_PASSWORD_HERE login.keychain


Disconnected the node from Jenkins master and reinitiated the connection.  The next build was a success.
Probably the build process was not able to sign the app, but the error message was not meaningful at all.
